# Error on Auth0 redirect urls (redirect URI is wrong) with Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: apache, nginx, auth0

We are using Auth0 for authentication and NGINX for reverse proxy.

***com.auth0.AuthenticationController*** is used at backend for the login and we updated all the setting at auth0 application and added these urls (http://localhost:8888,  http://localhost:9999 ) to allowed callback urls list.

Nginx reverse proxy configuration

```
  server {
      listen       8888;
      server_name  localhost;
        
      location = /login {
          proxy_pass http://localhost:9999/login;
      }
  }
```

As per the above code when nginx gets login request it redirects it to http://localhost:9999/login

The service running at ***localhost:9999*** is trying to get ***com.auth0.Token*** using the auth ***code***

```
authenticationController.handle(request, response);
```

but following exception is thrown.

***The redirect URI is wrong. You sent http://localhost:9999, and we expected http://localhost:8888***

**Note:** It is telling us that while creating the secret **code** at Auth0 we have provided http://localhost:8888 as redirect_uri, but trying to access the token using http://localhost:9999

How to tell the Auth0 server that it is proxied url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
server {
      listen       8888;
      server_name  localhost;
        
      location = /login {
    
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_pass http://localhost:9999/login;
      }
  }
```

The code started working when we added the following line to nginx configuration.

***proxy_set_header Host $http_host;***